# Issue creating and applying the migration that adds the director field to the movies table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the code I thought is correct:

```
rails generate migration AddDirectorsToMovies Directors:string
```

When I run `rake db:test:prepare`, the terminal tells me:

```
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again. The rake aborts.
```

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you run `rake db:migrate` first? That task will generate the schema file, which is then used by `rake db:test:prepare`.